# Unsolved problems for partition function

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integer-partitions, modular-forms

In number theory, the partition function $p(n)$ represents the number of possible partitions of a non-negative integer $n$. For instance, $p(4) = 5$ because the integer $4$ has the five partitions $1 + 1 + 1 + 1, 1 + 1 + 2, 1 + 3, 2 + 2$ and $4$. (Wikipedia)

Partition function has amazing properties, among which the most beautiful one is Ramanujan's congruences

$$p(5n+4)\equiv0\ (\text{mod}\ 5),\\p(7n+5)\equiv0\ (\text{mod}\ 7),\\p(11n+6)\equiv0\ (\text{mod}\ 11).$$

There are many problems remain open and I want to do some research at some of them. I list some open problems as follows:

---

- [**Second Borwein Conjecture**](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82228707.pdf)

For each positive number $n$, the polynomials $\alpha_n(q),\beta_n(q)$ and $\gamma_n(q)$ defined by

$$\prod_{j=1}^\infty(1-q^{3j-2})^2(1-q^{3j-1})^2=\alpha_n(q^3)-q\beta_n(q^3)-q^2\gamma_n(q^3),$$

each has non-negative coefficients.

---

- [**Third Borwein Conjecture**](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82228707.pdf)

For each positive number $n$, the polynomials $\nu_n(q),\phi_n(q),\chi_n(q),\psi_n(q)$ and $\omega_n(q)$ defined by

$$\prod_{j=1}^\infty(1-q^{5j-4})(1-q^{5j-3})(1-q^{5j-2})(1-q^{5j-1})
\\=\nu_n(q^5)-q\phi_n(q^5)-q^2\chi_n(q^5)-q^3\psi_n(q^5)-q^4\omega_n(q^5),$$

each has non-negative coefficients.

> Remark. The [First Borwein Conjecture](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82228707.pdf) is proved recently. See [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870821004679).

---

- **Prime Partition Numbers**

It is conjectured that $p(n)$ is prime for infinitely many $n$. However, I think this problems is much harder than the $n^2+1$ conjecture.

> Remark. It is easy to derive from [Ono's result](https://www.jstor.org/stable/121118) that every prime divides at least one value of $p(n)$.

---

- **Parity of Partition Function**

Prove that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\#\{m\leq n\,|\,p(m)\text{ is even}\}}{n}=\frac12.$$

---

- **Newman's Conjecture**

For each integer $r$ and $m$ with $0\leq r<m$, there are infinitely many $n$ such that $p(n)\equiv r\ (\text{mod}\ m)$. If possible, find the density of each residue modulo $m$.

> Remark. The conjecture is proved for all prime number $m\geq5$. See [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Matthew-Boylan-3/publication/226765327_Arithmetic_properties_of_the_partition_function/links/00b49526679642eeff000000/Arithmetic-properties-of-the-partition-function.pdf). Moreover, there are useful criteria to attack this conjecture. See [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/121118) and [here](https://www.pnas.org/doi/abs/10.1073/pnas.191488598).

---

I want to know more unsolved problems for partition function. And I hope this post will become a reference post.

Any supplement of other open problems is appreciated.

Comment: And where is question?

Comment: I want to know more unsolved problems for partition function. And I hope this post will become a reference post.

Comment: May be mathoverflow.net is more appropriate for such aim.

Comment: I think the College Math forum at AoPS is also a good place to ask for help.

Comment: I thought about to write Subbarao conjecture as an answer.  I saw it in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionPCongruences.html... But unfortunately I realized that it is proved as of today. It is not an open problem.

Comment: King and Park conjectures: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.08646.pdf